# Accessing button using ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not able to access the button using ref. Below is my code sample, In I keeping the undefined for completeSubmissionButton. I'm not sure what's the solution for it.

```
const completeSubmissionButton = useRef();

  <Button
          primary
          ref={completeSubmissionButton}
          className={buttonClassName}
          onClick={() => onCompleteSubmissionButtonClick()}
        >
          {"BtnName"}
        </Button>





useEffect(() => {
    console.log("completeSubmissionButton.current", completeSubmissionButton)

    const btnElement = completeSubmissionButton.current;
    
    if (btnElement) {
      console.log(btnElement);
    }
    
  });
```

Comment: How do you declare `completeSubmissionButton`?

Comment: In one case I'm doubting that you're not defining `ref` prop in the `Button` component which is not a primitive button

Comment: I don't get it? The button I'm using its from react components button

Comment: `Button` is a component (does not have ref by default) and `button` is a primitive element (always has ref by default). If you want to pass `ref` to `Button` (a component), you need to add `forwardRef` to your `Button` component. If you cannot control that because it's a component from a library, you can check the document to find where they pass refs.

Comment: I believe the ref should be working outside of useEffect hook (like method bind with a click e.t..c), can you check that? If yes, then do you need the ref in `useEffect`? Also, you can have a look at https://medium.com/welldone-software/usecallback-might-be-what-you-meant-by-useref-useeffect-773bc0278ae#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20respond,current%20using%20useRef%20. for ref in useEffect

Comment: @NickVu In code I have to move focus to button element once all the form elements are filled out so that screen reader can announce the complete button is enabled

Comment: Could you share that library name with me? I can see what they have in that button component @shanky

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were using some libraries :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't provide a ref to React component ,ref only work in a native html element so you need to pass your Button component into forwardRef fn

```
 import {useRef , forwardRef} from 'react';
 
 // your button component 

  const Button = forwardRef((props,ref)=>{

  return (
  <button ref={ref}>Click</button>
)    
})
    // other component 

   function App(){

   const btnRef = useRef(null) 

   return (
   <>
     <Button ref={btnRef}/>
   </>
)   
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Is that button component  custom-made or from any other library

Comment: actually it worked, I found the fix, thank you for your solution